# 2sxc - problem with editing after upgrade to DNN and 2sxc

Tags: upgrade, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have recently done some DNN version upgrades which included upgrading 2sxc as part of the process. After the upgrade, the 2sxc editor has text overlaying various buttons/links instead of showing icons. Please see screenshots attached.

DNN was upgraded from 09.02.02 to 09.11.00 and 2sxc went from 11.11.03 to 14.12.3 (both using the appropriate upgrade paths).

I have also done a clean new install of DNN 9.11.0 and 2sxc 14.12.3 and don't encounter this issue, it only seems to be when upgrading.

I have since found that if I upgrade 2sxc to 14.01.00 everything works fine.

Any suggestions?

```
[[Editor with text overlaid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1eDL.jpg)]
[Editor with text overlaid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7l4fv.jpg)
[Gallery editor with text overlaid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XMQg.jpg)
```

Please see images where text is overlaying buttons / links etc... especially the gallery images where you can't get to the links to edit / delete images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest 2sxc we're including the icon font (woff2) in the distribution.

This is because many customers have issues with things being loaded from Google CDNs (GPDR reasoning).

You are probably hosting it yourself or on azure, and you don't have woff2 as an allowed mime type. So the server refuses to serve the icon font.

Please check https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2971

Comment: Thanks ijungleBoy that has fixed my issue adding those 2 lines of code from that link.

Comment: perfect, best mark as answered